GeoPHP cannot find any lines contained or intersection my polygons by QGIS does
I have about 300 polygons delineating ski areas.  The GeoJSON is called aa_winter_sports_polygons.geojson.  I have thousands of ski runs (aka pistes) that either intersect the polygon or are contained within the polygon.  Ultimately, I want to sum the length of the lines but before I do that I have to get the script recognizing lines in/intersecting the polygon.  I have entered "Bingo!" for now to state whether the line in/intersected a polygon but no "bingo!" at all.
Here is my script:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$aa_winter_sports_polygonsGeoJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('aa_winter_sports_polygons.geojson'));
$aa_pistesGeoJSON  = json_decode(file_get_contents('aa_pistes.geojson'));

$i = 0;

// Loop through each feature (polygon) in the first collection
foreach ($aa_winter_sports_polygonsGeoJSON->features as $polygonFeature) {
    // Convert each polygon feature to a GeoPHP geometry object
    $polygon = geoPHP::load(json_encode($polygonFeature->geometry), 'json');


    // Loop through each feature (line) in the second collection
    foreach ($aa_pistesGeoJSON->features as $lineFeature) {
        
        // Convert each line feature to a GeoPHP geometry object
        $line = geoPHP::load(json_encode($lineFeature->geometry), 'json');

        // Check if the line is either contained within the polygon or intersects with it
        if ($polygon->contains($line) || $polygon->intersects($line)) {
            echo "bingo!</br>";

        }
        echo $i++.'</br>';
    }
}

When I sum up the lines in QGIS, every polygon has pistes within it so I am doing something wrong.

I found the solution. As a matter of fact "contains" is a feature from GEOS.  I installed GEOS and now it works.
